# Granting privileges doesn't work

Tags: plsql, oracle12c, privileges

I have created package with couple of procedures, which are working perfectly, when I access package using my own username and password (package owner's).
To access my package from another user ora17, I granted privileges:

```
grant execute on package_name TO ora17;
```

then from ora17 user I ran following:

```
CREATE SYNONYM package_name FOR LOGIN.package_name;
```

following teacher's instructions. 
Trying to access my program from browser, f.e. using url: `https://somehost/pls/st12/package_name.customers`
I am getting following error:

```
Thu, 28 Dec 2017 15:12:19 GMT

Failed to parse target procedure 
package_name.customers: PROCEDURE DOESN'T EXIST
```

What am I doing wrong here?

UPD:
executing

```
describe package_name;
```

it gives me error:

```
ORA-04043: object "LOGIN"."PACKAGE_NAME" does not exist
```

Comment: When you created the synonym, presumably you changed `LOGIN` to your actual user - the name of the schema the package is in? What happens if you try to call the procedure manually as `ora17`, e.g. from SQL Developer?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I am new to all this and don't know how to exactly run procedures from packages of other user. but when I am trying to compile package, I am getting error: Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: You shouldn't be compiling it from `ora17`. Although that error suggests the synonym is pointing to the right place. You said it works perfectly when run as the owner, so how are you doing that? How about something slightly simpler than executing then; what does `describe package_name` say, as ora17?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am accessing it by URL. This program is something like UI for database written with procedures. I updated question.

Comment: Again, is `LOGIN` actually your package-owner schema name, or have you changed it to that value in the create statement and error message when posting the question? What is the name of the schema that owns the package? And presumably your package has a different name, so are you sure you've used that consistently in all your commands?

Comment: @AlexPoole, thank you, I really should have put instead of LOGIN my owner's username. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this was simple, I just should have put owner's username instead of LOGIN here:

```
CREATE SYNONYM package_name FOR LOGIN.package_name;
```